# routerLink with non English

Tags: angular

I am using `routerLink` with Angular 2 and non English URL and its working fine

How can I make the `routerLink` display the URL in plain Hebrew and not in an encoded one ?

currently the URL is :
http://localhost:4200/#/topic/%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%9B

and I want it in plain Hebrew :
[http://localhost:4200/#/topic/מדעכ](http://localhost:4200/#/topic/%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%9B)

The string in the code that generate the link (topic.slug) is in plain Hebrew

`<a [routerLink]="['/topic', topic.slug]" class="preview-link">`

Comment: As I know browser itself should do all non-alphabet symbols